# using oracle db. getting in the following statements."ORA-00936: missing expression" , how to fix this?

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

hi i am using oracle db. getting in the following statements."ORA-00936: missing expression"

```
string sqlquery = ("select parent from tn2 where CONNECT BY PRIOR child=" + node);
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.60.212.62)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)));User Id=apex_demo;Password=apex_demo;";
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlquery, con);
        adapter.Fill(objDT1);
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the SQL statement. It is not allowed when executing SQL statements from .NET.
Also, the `where` is invalid here, because you don't provide a condition. The `CONNECT BY PRIOR` is no `where` condition but a construct on its own. See [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html) for more info on how to use `CONNECT BY PRIOR`.

Comment: Then put back the single quotes you had there originally. BTW: Does your table tn2 really have a column `child` with the value "level-1-1-767"?